# C: program prints garbage text even after structs are freed

Tags: c, memory-management, struct, malloc, free

I have a program with the following structs:

```
typedef struct slide
{
    int number;
    int maxX;
    int y;
    int r, g, b;
    struct line *first;
} slide;

typedef struct line {
    char content[256]; // number subject to change
    int r, g, b;
    struct line *prev;
    struct line *next;
} line;
```

Creating instances of these structs is done with the following code:

```
slide* createSlideArray(int s) {
    slide* slides = malloc(sizeof(struct slide)*s);
    return slides;
}

line *nextLine(line *prev) {
    line *n = malloc(sizeof(line));
    n->prev = prev;
    prev->next = n;
    return n;
}
```

And finally here is the code to free the structs after the program loop finishes, and before a new file is opened:

```
void freeLines(line *l) {
    line *next;
    while(l) {
        next = l->next;
        free(l);
        l = next;
    }
}
```

in main:

```
int i;
for (i=0;i<slideCount;i++) {
    freeLines(slides[i].first); // works through next till NULL
}
free(slides);
```

As you can see, an instance of the slide struct holds a "first" line struct, the line struct is a doubly linked list. The line's content is read to the screen (using ncurses)

While in the program loop the user can type a command `:open filename` to open a new file, this is where my issue lies.

This slides and lines should be freed. When the loop starts again it'll open a new file, create the slides and lines, and use them as the content. The content, however, is partially filled with garbage text. I'm pretty sure this issue is in the lines struct and how it is being free. I'm not seeing that I'm doing wrong however.

Edit: I should make it clear that on the first iteration of the program the text is perfect, it is only when I try to parse a new file that the garbage text appears, and it is very homogeneous (appears at the front of each line, same characters)

I'm on Ubuntu if that makes a difference.

Here is a link to the project: [DSS](https://github.com/codythegreat/dss)

Comment: Neither `malloc` not `free` "clear" the previous data in the memory.

Comment: I tried using `memset` to clear the memory, but that didn't seem to help (unless I was just using it wrong.) Would that have cleared it?

Comment: Could you expand on why that line is not good? If I can improve the code I'm all for changing it. I just started learning C 2 weeks ago so anything helps.

Comment: I am sorry but I doubt that anyone is going to browse through your project on github. You are welcome here as a new contributor and you might benefit from taking the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and reading [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Please post the [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows the problem, in the question.

Comment: Hmm so I guess I need to rework my question? Thank you for those links. I'll read through them later and see if I can post a better version what I had asked.

Comment: I cloned your repo and I couldn't reproduce the error :D the slides work fine.

Comment: If a program prints garbage, adding `free` is unlikely to cause it not to print garbage (and if so, that's evidence of something being  wrong). There is no "even" about it.

Comment: I think the issue might be the `content[256]` array. Maybe the content overflows and writes garbage to the next slide. which could be the case if you maximize your terminal and the screen is big?

Comment: Kaz the program doesn't print garbage until the second iteration, Everything that comes before it is garbage free (so to speak.) If a user decides to open a file, then I've added code to free the information obtained from the old file, and then use the same main loop to get the new information from the file to be opened. This is where the garbage is appearing.

Comment: Adam I have been theorizing that it might be that array. I'm not sure if there is a better solution to storing/disposing of the contents that are written to that array. I thought about using a char pointer and allocating memory to the exact size of each line... I might try that later tonight.

Comment: I tried setting it to a smaller size but the overflow was detected and the program crashed. maybe I was lucky because the program wrote to some read-only chunk.

Comment: How do you do a second iteration? like how do you open two files in the same run?

Comment: Adam did you get this error: `terminal size/zoom error: Please resize or zoom out the terminal to display the slide.` ? if so that is normal, it is a soft error that I wrote in for zooming in/out too far.

Comment: You can open two files by typing `:` and it should open command mode, then type `open filename` with filename being whatever you want

Comment: I have disabled this feature however, if you'd like to enable it you'll need to uncomment lines 72-74 of display.c file

Comment: haha it says the feature is still not implemented. That's my time for today :D good luck fixing it though. I like it :D

Comment: Adam thank you for your help and your time! Sorry about that error message; I left it in so that people who just want to use the program won't have to experience the awful mess that that feature is producing at the moment haha.

Comment: @4386427 there is nothing wrong with that line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some clear issues that I can spot from reading the code in your post. I can't definitively say if these are responsible for your problem as the code in your post is not a compilable example and I didn't go delving into your linked project.

**Your nextLine function**:

You have neglected to set n->next.

You have also neglected setting the prev pointer of the following node if there is one. ( prev->next->prev if prev->next != NULL ).

You current design precludes you from using this function to setup the first node in the list. It also does not show how you intend to create that node.

This function does not allow you to add a node to the begining of the list.

**Your createSlideArray function:**

This function does not initialize the slides it creates. These slide instances must be initialized. It seems sensible to do it here, but you might have a good reason to do it elsewhere. In either case, initializing the slideObject.first member is critical. Without this you will not be able to tell if the slide has a list of lines or not and your freeLines function will fail as it will be passed garbage as its parameter.

**Note:**

A different way of implementing doubly linked lists is using a "head node" which is always present and links to the first and last node in the list. This simplifies some issues, but changes others. You can research this if you are interested.

Comment: Hi Avi thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I should have noted that I actually "manually" initiated the first line and then with each line there after I used the next line function to fill in the other lines. When I got to the end of the lines I simply set the next/prev values to the last line and moved on with the program loop.    As for initializing the slides I do that elsewhere (in a while loop over the text file) which is also where the first line node is created.

Comment: OK, that could work. Do be careful not to break it in future code revisions. Sounds like you will have to look elsewhere for your problem. Debugger, here comes Cody.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by simply making proper calls to `memset`. for lines I was able to do the following:

`memset(l, 0, sizeof(*l));`

It is important that you are getting the size of the value at the l pointer, and not the size of the pointer itself, otherwise you won't properly free the memory. This was the issue that I was facing.